# How to make tabs with pure JS?

Tags: javascript, html, css, menu, tabs

i'am trying to do a "tab" menu with only pure JS CSS and HTML, where basically i have 7 divs with content and 7 "buttons" which should open the matching div. The strategy i want to use is to put all the divs with the "hidden" or the "Display: none" attribute stacked in the same spot and then, when i click on button it turns it´s matching div to visible. The problem i am facing is how to tell the button which div it should open (using arrays instead of doing it manually), and how to set it back to invisible when i click in other div (i was thinking about an if() that just turns on the visibility if the number of the button selected matches the number of the div, but supposedly every button has a div, so i am confused).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you want something like this?

```js
document.addEventListener('click', ({ target: { dataset: { id = '' }}}) => {
  if (id.length > 0) {
    document.querySelectorAll('.tab').forEach(t => t.classList.add('hidden'));
    document.querySelector(`#${id}`).classList.remove('hidden');
  }
});
```

```css
.hidden {
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<button data-id="tab1">tab 1</button>
<button data-id="tab2">tab 2</button>
<div id="tab1" class="tab">Tab 1</div>
<div id="tab2" class="tab hidden">Tab 2</div>
```

But the reality is we probably don't want to actually use `button`.
So lets change that up.

```js
const tabClick = ({ target }) => {
    const { dataset: { id = '' }} = target;
    document.querySelectorAll('.tab').forEach(t => t.classList.remove('selected'));
    target.classList.add('selected');
    document.querySelectorAll('.tab-panel').forEach(t => t.classList.add('hidden'));
    document.querySelector(`#${id}`).classList.remove('hidden');
};

const bindTabs = () => {
  document.querySelectorAll('.tab').forEach(tab => {
    tab.addEventListener('click', tabClick);
  })
};

// Belts and braces, lets ensure our DOM is loaded and only assign click to the `tabs`
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  bindTabs();
});
```

```css
.tab {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: grey;
  padding: 0.75rem;
  color: #fff;
}

.selected {
  background-color: black;
}

.tab-panel {
  
  border: 2px solid black;
  min-height: 50px;
  max-width: 250px;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.hidden {
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<div data-id="tab1" class="tab selected">tab 1</div>
<div data-id="tab2" class="tab">tab 2</div>
<div data-id="tab3" class="tab">tab 3</div>
<div data-id="tab4" class="tab">tab 4</div>
<div id="tab1" class="tab-panel">Tab 1</div>
<div id="tab2" class="tab-panel hidden">Tab 2</div>
<div id="tab3" class="tab-panel hidden">Tab 3</div>
<div id="tab4" class="tab-panel hidden">Tab 4</div>
```

So how can we approach this with `basic` javascript.

```js
const tabCount = 4; // If we add a new tab, increase.

const tabClick = (event) => {
    const tabButtonClicked = event.target;
    const id = event.target.dataset.id;
    
    // First remove selected and hide all tabs
    for(let i = 1; i <= tabCount; i++) {
      let tabButtonID = "#tabButton" + i;
      let tabButton = document.querySelector(tabButtonID);
      let tabID = "#" + tabButton.dataset.id;
      let tab = document.querySelector(tabID);
      tabButton.classList.remove("selected");
      tab.classList.add("hidden");
    }
    
    // Now we set selected and show the selected tab.
    document.querySelector("#" + id).classList.remove("hidden");
    tabButtonClicked.classList.add("selected");
};

const bindTabs = () => {
  // Loop through number of tabs and add a click event.
  for(let i = 1; i <= tabCount; i++) {
    let tabButtonID = "#tabButton" + i;
    let tabButton = document.querySelector(tabButtonID);
    tabButton.addEventListener('click', tabClick);
  }
};

// Belts and braces, lets ensure our DOM is loaded and only assign click to the `tabs`
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  bindTabs();
});
```

```css
.tab {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: grey;
  padding: 0.75rem;
  color: #fff;
}

.selected {
  background-color: black;
}

.tab-panel {
  
  border: 2px solid black;
  min-height: 50px;
  max-width: 250px;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.hidden {
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<div id="tabButton1" data-id="tab1" class="tab selected">tab 1</div>
<div id="tabButton2" data-id="tab2" class="tab">tab 2</div>
<div id="tabButton3" data-id="tab3" class="tab">tab 3</div>
<div id="tabButton4" data-id="tab4" class="tab">tab 4</div>
<div id="tab1" class="tab-panel">Tab 1</div>
<div id="tab2" class="tab-panel hidden">Tab 2</div>
<div id="tab3" class="tab-panel hidden">Tab 3</div>
<div id="tab4" class="tab-panel hidden">Tab 4</div>
```

Comment: That's exactly the result i want, the problem is that i am working for a university project, and we never learned some of those functions, and I wanted to do this with basic stuff, which probably is harder to do, but I needed to understand what i am doing, anyway thanks for the response, I really appreciate it!

Comment: Ok, what functions do you not know? (Please vote for the answer if it is useful)

Comment: we do basic stuff like add a class to a div, then having it in the CSS so for example i start it with the display none in CSS then when i do a function in JS that changes the class name to Show for example and i style de class show to visible, like when you do basic burguer menus. The hardest part here is that i have more than 1 "button" or clickable div... Basically i don't know any "dataset", "target" ".foreach"

Comment: I will add a 'basic' version after dinner

Comment: thank you so much, it would be perfect if i could use a "for" cicle to add event listeners to every "button"

Comment: I added a third version that uses loops etc. Hope that helps.